# Output arrays in format that can be compared with Python numpy

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, format

Is there a way to convert an array in *Mathematica* such that its output format resembles that of Python's numpy arrays? I want to go from:

```
{{0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.0625, -0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, 
  0, 0, -0.125, 0.0625, 0, 0}, 
 {-0.0625, 0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, 
  0, 0, 0, -0.0625, 0, 0}}
```

to something that looks like this:

```python
np.array([
  [0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.0625, -0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, 
   0, 0, -0.125, 0.0625, 0, 0], 
  [-0.0625, 0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, 
   0, 0, 0, -0.0625, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Related: [How to convert a Mathematica list in a Python list?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71626).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty method to do it,

```
input = {{0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.0625, -0.1875, 
   0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, 0, 0, -0.125, 0.0625, 0, 0}, {-0.0625, 
   0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, 0, 0, 
   0, -0.0625, 0, 0}}
(* {{0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.0625, -0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625,
   0.0625, 0, 0, -0.125, 0.0625, 0, 0}, {-0.0625, 0.1875, 
  0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, -0.0625,
   0, 0}} *)
```

First I convert the list to a string, then I use `StringReplace` and copy the result to the clipboard to paste wherever I need it,

```
CopyToClipboard@
 StringReplace[
  ToString@input, {"{{" -> "np.array([[", "}, {" -> "], [", 
   "}}" -> "]])"}]
```

The output has no line breaks,

```python
np.array([[0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.0625, -0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, 0, 0, -0.125, 0.0625, 0, 0], [-0.0625, 0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, -0.0625, 0, 0]])
```

A more polished, functional form, which can deal with differently shaped arrays, and with large and small numbers, is

```
toNumpy = CopyToClipboard[
    "np.array(" <>
     StringReplace[
      ToString[
       Map[FortranForm, #, {-1}]]
      , {"{" -> "[", "}" -> "]"}] <> ")"
    ] &;
```

Some test cases,

```
toNumpy@RandomReal[10^13, {2, 2, 2}]

np.array([[[6.515662614124779e12, 5.006958562518258e12], [9.038456654284738e12, 6.155528971184453e12]], [[8.352734900856066e12, 3.183407977590039e11], [9.3300341220833e12, 4.83956443633259e12]]])
```

and

```
toNumpy@RandomReal[10^-13, {5}]

np.array([2.5981516628601564e-14, 8.152269536832112e-14, 5.284716124977113e-16, 5.3549719092414376e-14, 2.877505407608681e-14])
```

Comment: I try to run the `toNumpy` versions and they don't give any output on my computer.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you wanted to paste it somewhere to compare with python, or paste into your python code directly, so I put `CopyToClipboard` in the function.  Just hit paste and it will come out. Just erase that part if you'd rather have it in the notebook

Comment: @AlejandroMarcosAragon, there is no output!

Comment: @Developer2000 Open a text editor and paste the result.  :-)

Comment: @JasonB, I did not understand what did you say!?

Comment: The result is in the clipboard, you have to paste it somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

I've prepared a Module to handle such conversions (original answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144200/48312).  It would work like this for Alejandro's question:

```
ToPython[{{0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.0625, -0.1875, 0.0625, -0.0625,
0.0625, 0, 0, -0.125, 0.0625, 0, 0}, {-0.0625, 0.1875, 
0.0625, -0.0625, 0.0625, -0.1875, -0.0625, 0.0625, 0, 0, 
0, -0.0625, 0, 0}}]
```

The output in Mathematica would be a string (that is directly copied to clipboard)

```
numpy.array( [numpy.array( [0.1875e0,(-0.625e-1),0.625e-1,(-0.625e-1),         (-0.1875e0),0.625e-1,(-0.625e-1),0.625e-1,0,0,(-0.125e0),0.625e-1,0,0,]     ),numpy.array( [(-0.625e-1),0.1875e0,0.625e-1,(-0.625e-1),0.625e-1,(-0.1875e0),    (-0.625e-1),0.625e-1,0,0,0,(-0.625e-1),0,0,] ),] )
```

Once copied and interpret by Numpy...

```
array([[ 0.1875, -0.0625,  0.0625, -0.0625, -0.1875,  0.0625, -0.0625,
     0.0625,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.125 ,  0.0625,  0.    ,  0.    ],
   [-0.0625,  0.1875,  0.0625, -0.0625,  0.0625, -0.1875, -0.0625,
     0.0625,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    , -0.0625,  0.    ,  0.    ]])
```