# How to export an output matrix obtained in mathematica to a matrix in python with the correct format?

Tags: matrix, export, sparse-arrays, python

I have a large sparse matrix as the output and I want to save the output and open it as a matrix in python. The output is a 6000 x 6000 matrix and I don't know how to make changes to the file such that it opens as a matrix in python with the correct format i.e. [[1 0 0 ...],[1 ... 0],[...]]

Comment: So your matrix is sparse, right?

Comment: Yeah, the matrix is sparse. It is an incidence matrix that I got using data from a bipartite graph.

Comment: Shoulda mentioned that to begin with.

Answer (score 8):

I think for this kind of matrix it is better to use some of the dedicated matrix formats, like, "MTX" (of [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/)) or "HarwellBoeing". Below are two examples using "MTX": one with a dense 6000x6000 matrix and one with a sparse matrix.

### Dense matrix

#### Mathematica

```
mat = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {6000, 6000}];
Export["/path/RandomMat.mtx", mat, "MTX"]
```

#### Python

```
>>> from numpy import array, matrix
>>> from scipy.io import mmread, mmwrite
>>> A = mmread("/path/RandomMat.mtx")
A = mmread("/path/RandomMat.mtx")
>>> A
A
array([[ 0.78126179,  0.35847388,  0.68474351, ...,  0.583692  ,
         0.80156363,  0.04288801],
       [ 0.28195085,  0.25645955,  0.25975606, ...,  0.757864  ,
         0.77155917,  0.23542805],
       [ 0.60189668,  0.99310095,  0.25748816, ...,  0.13496221,
         0.8505471 ,  0.49982663],
       ..., 
       [ 0.46228175,  0.72703853,  0.16218388, ...,  0.34214427,
         0.58023789,  0.06454413],
       [ 0.21502725,  0.01252058,  0.06348292, ...,  0.79366921,
         0.0165515 ,  0.36357833],
       [ 0.43135125,  0.38405678,  0.02897838, ...,  0.69190792,
         0.51890882,  0.52854666]])
```

### Sparse matrix

#### Mathematica

```
gr = RandomGraph[{100, 200}];
grmat = AdjacencyMatrix[gr]
Export["/path/RandomGraphMat.mtx", grmat, "MTX"]
```

#### Python

```
>>> from numpy import array, matrix
>>> from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, lil_matrix
>>> from scipy.io import mmread, mmwrite
>>> B = mmread("/path/RandomGraphMat.mtx")
B = mmread("/path/RandomGraphMat.mtx")
>>> B
B
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
```

Comment: I'm getting this error. I had to used a rectangular matrix.

IncidenceMatrix[SparseArray[Automatic, {6613, 6700}, 0, {<<1>>}]] cannot be exported to the MatrixMarket format

Comment: @jazzytortoise It seems that the object you are trying to export is not a matrix.

Answer (score 4):

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
(mat = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Export["mat.txt", mat, "CSV"]
```

Open python and type

```
>python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2

>>> f = open ( 'mat.txt' , 'r')
>>> mat =  [ map(float,line.split(',')) for line in f ]
>>> print(mat)

[[0.2801766771080665, 0.616846438123569, 0.5567596750781629,    0.9343768938387196, 0.6557793334016284], 
[0.18935521644817044, 0.3006971747527434, 0.8805922006965157, 0.4281395790014586, 0.6450351079034391],
[0.7002938047712715, 0.9699463636247314, 0.7421654618136742, 0.7459397473691496, 0.8102422840022152], 
[0.753607490381512, 0.37223385719235136, 0.5181277708575103, 0.9934363269082769, 0.9389620252730952], 
[0.7270038190913004, 0.33165312990950047, 0.42576541711433946, 0.9697810988851399, 0.5567071842453715]]
>>> mat[0][0]
0.2801766771080665
>>> mat[0][1]
0.616846438123569
>>>
```

Another option is to use CSV module in Python to read the matrix.

Comment: I'm not able to print mat[0][1]. It shows me this error.

TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @jazzytortoise It works for me. May be different Python version? I am using 2.7.6 on Linux.